# iOS: Crashlytics Crash Reports and Free RAM

Tags: ios, memory, crash-reports

In one of our iPhone apps, we have gotten a few Crashlytics crashes that we have, so far, been unable to reproduce.  However, on closer inspection, I noticed a bit of a trend...

---

Crash 1: -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:]

Free RAM: 10%

---

Crash 2: -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:]

Free RAM: 8%

---

Crash 3: HostBase::lock()

Free RAM: 8%

---

Crash 4:-[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:]

Free RAM: 22%

---

Does the amount of free RAM mean anything?  Can we be sure that these are actual crashes and not our app getting killed by the OS due to low memory?  Does Crashlytics send crash reports if the app crashes while in the background?

Added a couple stack traces...

Exception Type: SIGSEGV, Nav Crashes

```
0    libobjc.A.dylib    
objc_msgSend + 15
1    UIKit ✭    
-[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] + 274
2    UIKit  
-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 158
3    UIKit  
-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 50
4    QuartzCore 
CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 208
5    libdispatch.dylib  
_dispatch_client_callout + 22
6    libdispatch.dylib  
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 224
7    CoreFoundation 
__CFRunLoopRun + 1290
8    CoreFoundation 
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
9    CoreFoundation 
CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
10   GraphicsServices   
GSEventRunModal + 74
11   UIKit  
UIApplicationMain + 1120
```

Exception Type: SIGSEGV, HostLock crash

```
0    libobjc.A.dylib    
objc_msgSend + 15
1    CFNetwork ✭    
HostBase::lock() + 14
2    CFNetwork  
DispatchHost::performInvocation(void const*) + 12
3    CFNetwork  
__setupTCPConnection_block_invoke_2 + 290
4
...
libsystem_network.dylib 
__tcp_connection_notify_complete_block_invoke_1 + 18
7    libsystem_c.dylib  
_pthread_wqthread + 294
```

Comment: What is the exception type and could you show a little more of the stack traces? Right now one could only do wild guesses.

Comment: Sure, added them in.  I'm trying to figure out if the amount of available RAM left (such a small amount) has anything to do with the problem (such as the OS killing my app and it appearing as a crash), or if the low RAM is just a red herring.

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but for other's sake.  The fact that an app is killed in low memory conditions, doesn't mean it's not the primary hog.  Apps crash in low memory conditions because various resource allocation calls begin sporadically failing.  If you're leaking memory, your app may be responsible for putting itself in such constrained memory conditions.  Some of these conditions you can properly handle and some you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8% memory can be a lot, I highly doubt that this is an issue. I don't know if they send crashes while running in the background, you have to ask them directly since their SDK is not open source.

Both exception stack traces you added hint at a memory problem.

The first one looks like it tries to call a delegate at the end of an animation of an object, which does not exist any more.

The second one looks like a similar problem, where the completion block is accessing an object that is gone. So you might check your blocks for such patterns.